# Skype won't install from terminal!

Tags: command-line, software-installation, skype

For some reason it won't let me install skype!
I looked at this link [How to install skype in ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775087/how-to-install-skype-in-ubuntu-16-04) 
typed these:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install skype
```

and got these error messages:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package skype
```

Thank you for all the help!

Comment: Did you enable the `partners` repository? Do you have 32 bit architecture enabled?

Comment: I don't know. I'm new and just got ubuntu working today.

Comment: Enabling the partner repo through GUI or commandline is described in both answers to the question you linked and enabling 32bit architecture from the command-line is described in the second answer there. But it's probably the partner repo which is missing.

Comment: Why is this marked as duplicate?

Comment: Also, please tell me in a step-by-step process please!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Install the new version, which is a lot better then the ancient 4.3 version. It does not support video calls at the moment (unless you both are using Skype for Linux Alpha), but everything else has been working very well for me.

**1.** Download the DEB from [here](https://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/Skype-for-Linux-Alpha-and-calling-on-Chrome-amp-Chromebooks/td-p/4434299).

**2.** Double click to install it.

Comment: That's the *new* Skype for Linux *Alpha* version. It's not ready for productive use.

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 16.04.01 not linux alpha

Comment: @UbuntuUser It is "Skype for Linux" Alpha. It's a new and not yet stable development version of Skype that is completely different from the traditional Skype client for Linux.

Comment: What is the download name for terminal?