# Skype For Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, skype

I really want to install Skype on Ubuntu 16.04 but i don't know how

I've tried this: [How to install skype in ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775087/how-to-install-skype-in-ubuntu-16-04), but it didn't work; I get a message saying it can't locate the Skype package.

I have also installed the `.deb` from the official Skype site but that didn't work either; in the software store it said *installing* and went back to *install*.

When I do this:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install skype
```

It just says it's installing and then ends up with this:

```
E: Unable to locate package skype
```

Comment: Have you enabled [Canonical Partner](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/addremove-sources.html#canonical-partner)?

Comment: i did it still doesn't work

Comment: I use version 4.3.0.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 from the repros. I have not downloaded any .deb files separately.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is a completely useless problem description. Please open a terminal window and run `sudo apt update && sudo apt install skype`. If that doesn't succeed, then edit your question and show us the exact output from those commands.

Comment: it can't locate the skype package

Comment: Then you haven't enabled Canonical Partner.

Comment: i did it doesn't want to work

Comment: great now softwares and updates won't open -.-

Answer (score 0):

> **The `.deb` for *Ubuntu 12.04 (multiarch)* from [the official `Skype` webpage](https://get.skype.com/go/getskype-linux-beta-ubuntu-64) does work.**

---

If the Software Center gives you trouble installing it, you can try with **`GDebi Package Installed`** other tool to install `.deb` files.

- Install `GDebi` using `sudo apt install gdebi`.
- Right click the `.deb` file downloaded from the given link, *Open with...* and select `GDebi`.
- Follow the instructions given by the installer.

Done, now you have **Skype** installed on your computer, just open it and check everything works properly.

---

- Extra

Notice that it is a really old version of Skpye as Microsoft bought it and did not support the linux version anylonger, but still works just fine.

As @xangua commented: *Skype say the launch of the new Skype for Linux client reaffirms “our commitment to the Linux community.”* You can read more about in [this article from omgubuntu](https://omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/07/skype-linux-alpha).

Comment: Regarding of the comment of "as Microsoft bought it and did not support the linux version anylonger". Skype say the launch of the new Skype for Linux client reaffirms “our commitment to the Linux community.” http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/07/skype-linux-alpha

Comment: Thanks for that! Added the information, as well as the source,  and mentioned you.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/   $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install skype
```

and then Skype icon to show on applications I did:

```
sudo apt-get install sni-qt:i386
```