# Skype installation error

Tags: skype

I tried to install `skype` following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775087/how-to-install-skype-in-ubuntu-16-04?newreg=a314c4c03945471c8274130d8f95ab81) guide. 
But whenever i run command: `sudo apt install skype`, i get this message:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are installing another package simultaneously?
If yes, wait for it to finish.
If not:

The first thing you should try is killing the process.

```
ps aux | grep apt
```

If the output is any apt or apt-get process that seems stuck you can kill it with

```
kill processnumber
```

or if that does not work use

```
kill -9 processnumber
```

If both dont work, you can try to remove the lock-file with

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock 
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

Be careful with this! Try the other option first! You could possibly end up with a broken system.
After that try to install it again.